# Visualizing vanishing sets, online tools for algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, big-list, math-software, online-resources

Is there an online tool which can visualize algebraic sets such as $V(x+xy^2)$ or similar vanishing sets?

More generally, are there some neat programs found online, which help getting a grasp of such things.

I heard of the project "Imaginary" by the Oberwolfach Institute in Germany, but I do not find any results which are helpful. At least not in regards of the question above.
Most of the listed projects seem to be not serious, but fun computational tools.

Which helpful tools do you know?

Is Python, Mathematica, or any other mathematical software able to help with visualization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least for $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, you can use Desmos, like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hp6x1ugqmf

Comment: Ah, cool. I just figured that geogebra can scetch this. Thank you.